# How to make water flow sensor work to measure flowed water and not flow rate

Tags: arduino, sensor, c++, flow-sensor

I am using the [YF-S201 water flow sensor.](http://www.mantech.co.za/datasheets/products/yf-s201_sea.pdf) I am using this to fill up bottles. I need to know how to alter the below code in a way that instead of measuring flow rate it measures water passed through.

```
volatile int flow_frequency; // Measures flow sensor pulses
// Calculated litres/hour
 float vol = 0.0,l_minute;
unsigned char flowsensor = 2; // Sensor Input
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long cloopTime;


int SolenoidPumpPin=6;

// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void flow () // Interrupt function
{
   flow_frequency++;
}


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(SolenoidPumpPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, HIGH); //Switch Solenoid ON
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(flowsensor, INPUT);
   digitalWrite(flowsensor, HIGH); 
   Serial.begin(9600);

attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(flowsensor), flow, RISING); // Setup Interrupt
currentTime = millis();
   cloopTime = currentTime;


}

void loop() 
{



  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH)
  {
    currentTime = millis();
   // Every second, calculate and print litres/hour
   if(currentTime >= (cloopTime + 1000))
   {
      cloopTime = currentTime; // Updates cloopTime
      // Pulse frequency (Hz) = 7.5Q, Q is flow rate in L/min.
      l_minute = (flow_frequency / 7.5); // (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5Q = flowrate in 
L/hour
      /*lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Rate: ");
      lcd.print(l_minute);
      lcd.print(" L/M");*/
      l_minute = l_minute/60;
      //lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      vol = vol +l_minute;
      /*lcd.print("Vol:");
      lcd.print(vol);
      lcd.print(" L");*/
      flow_frequency = 0; // Reset Counter
      float Vollume = (l_minute*cloopTime)/1000;
      //Serial.print(l_minute, DEC); // Print litres/hour
      //Serial.println(" L/Sec");
  
    while(Vollume<=0.750)
    {
      digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, LOW);
      Serial.println(Vollume);
      Vollume = (l_minute*cloopTime)/1000;
  
    }
   }

    else {
      /*lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Rate: ");
      lcd.print( flow_frequency );
      lcd.print(" L/M");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("Vol:");
      lcd.print(vol);
      lcd.print(" L");*/
    }
    digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, HIGH);







 
  } 


}
```

Comment: Why not measure the total mass of the bottle plus liquid. Once the full value is reached then stop.

Comment: @SolarMike you mean using a weighing scale? It would be not a good idea, the turbulence caused by water would distort the weight readings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the flow rate vs output frequency, it's fairly linear. If you don't mind a few % error and just assume that it *is* linear that makes this very easy.

Simply count the pulses coming out of the flow meter. 1 pulse will be a fixed qty of water. 600 L/H corresponds to 82 * 3600 = 295,200 pulses/hr. So 600L = 295,200 pulses.

A good way to count the pulses would be to use an [external interrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/); aka an interrupt that fires every time the water meter produces a falling edge (or rising, doesn't matter). Inside the interrupt routine, simply increment a counter. You'll probably want to make it a 64 bit unsigned integer so log for a long time without overflowing (literally, heh).

Comment: This is correct: "Simply count the pulses coming out of the flow meter. 1 pulse will be a fixed qty of water". The OP is already doing this, but the pulse count is then used to calculate the flow rate, and the flow rate is then used to calculate the quantity of liquid passed.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Are you sure about the math? I changed the code to this while(flow_frequency<=1910)
    {
      digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, LOW);
      Serial.println(Vollume);
      flow_frequency++;
  
    }               for 750ml I should need to put the condition at 369 pulses in the "While", but I have to put it at aprox 1900 to get the bottle filled. ALso if I press the button again mid filling then it overshoots the mark, why is that, how to avoid that?

Comment: @tiktok - " if I press the button again mid filling then it overshoots the mark, why is that, how to avoid that?" Because when you press the button the seond time it starts the process all over. You avoid it by adding a new variable, call it process_state, which starts at zero. When the button is pushed, you check the value of process_state. If it is zero, you set it to some other value and begin operation. If process_state is not zero, you simply ignore buttonpush. When the loop total reaches your limit, you set process_control to zero and close out the loop.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thanks. I thought the button push could not be read again as the while loop is still running.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast can you suggest how this would take shape in code?

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the conversion table into lookup memory for more accuracy on interpolation as it has some nonlinearity.

LPH / 3600 x 1000 = mL/s  (milli-Litres per sec. Vs pulse per second)  to get millilitres per pulse ml/p  then volume / pulse = volume/s [ml/s] / pulse/s [Hz] = [ml/p]

```
 LPH  ml/s  Hz   ml/p
----- ----  ---  ----
 120  33.3  16   33.3/16  = 2.08
 240  66.7  32.5 66.7/32.5= 2.05
 720  200   90.2 200/90.2 = 2.22
```

( needs to be expanded in a spreadsheet with tolerances )

You can also create a complex formula in excel curve fit like a 3rd or 5th order equation and measure frequency by counts that change volume per count with the algorithm.  But look up tables are easier perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Take the flow rate to frequency table and convert it into to fluid per pulse table, then every time a pulse comes count that as a bit more fluid delivered.
look at the time ellaspsed since the last pulse to guess how much fluid that was.

Note that at higher flow rates the device is slightly more sensitive.

Really turbine flow sensors like this are the wrong type for fluid metering.
you should instead use a displacement meter like nutating disk meters.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if you keep the flow rate between 600l/hr and 120l/hr you can  use 2.05ml/pulse and get a fill within -1.8%/+0.9%. You can graph the flow rate during the fill and get an idea of how consistent the rate is, according to the flowmeter.

As with any of these paddle wheel flowmeters, you can drip liquid through at a slow rate indefinitely and get no pulses at all due to friction so you will get better results if you can control the flow within a reasonable range. That might involve a different type of pump. Of course if  you used a dispensing pump (positive displacement) you might not even need the flowmeter.

Since empirically your deviation is very large from my predicted 366 pulses, perhaps the flowmeter takes some time to get up to speed. You could also consider bypassing the dispensing (pumping back into the reservoir through the flowmeter) for a short time and then opening a valve to the dispenser and simultaneously closing an exactly similar valve to the recirculation. I would also have a look at the waveform from the flowmeter to verify that it is "clean" square waves and you're not getting multiple short pulses at the transitions which the MCU could easily respond to, since you're feeding it into an interrupt.

[image]

And, of course, check your code with something like a bench signal generator replacing the sensor. This is the sort of situation where a bit of equipment (scope, logic analyzer, signal generator with multiple channels) can save a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this dispensing pump option, I am actually trying to make a variable volume filling machine. Your idea about simultaneous valve operation I am going to test. But are you happy with my change in code, where I have made changes to the while loop? Is going "flow_frequency++; " the right way to go about it. I just need to be sure. (Refer my comment to Drew)

Comment: And I am using a 600L/H pump (At least it said so on Amazon).

Comment: Can sensor orientation have an effect? I have it oriented in a way that the bulb is downwards and the wires come out from the bottom.